# Input 0 where there is no value in R data frame

Tags: r, count

I want to get a data.frame like the one below, but including all years per topic. This one I made counts the number of items by year for each topic but when there is no item in some year, it just doesn't create that row for that particular topic, and it's blank in the final graph. Could anyone please tell me how to add the missing year with Count == 0 for the topics that have no value?

```
dtd2 <- structure(list(Topic = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("Topic 1", 
"Topic 10", "Topic 11", "Topic 12", "Topic 2", "Topic 3", "Topic 4", 
"Topic 5", "Topic 6", "Topic 7", "Topic 8", "Topic 9"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("2011", 
    "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"
    ), class = "factor"), Count = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 
    17L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 18L, 23L, 19L, 15L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 17L, 7L, 1L, 
    3L, 6L, 4L, 20L, 21L, 18L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 
    5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 23L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    6L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
    11L, 11L, 28L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 16L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dtd2, aes(x = Year, y = Count, colour = Topic, group = Topic)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + labs(x = "Year", y = NULL, title = "Timeline")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A time series approach could be

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
library(tsibble)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tsibble'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     interval, new_interval
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     id


dtd2 <- structure(list(Topic = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
  5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
  7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
  10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
  11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("Topic 1", 
    "Topic 10", "Topic 11", "Topic 12", "Topic 2", "Topic 3", "Topic 4", 
    "Topic 5", "Topic 6", "Topic 7", "Topic 8", "Topic 9"), class = "factor"), 
  Year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("2011", 
      "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"
    ), class = "factor"), Count = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 
      17L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
      5L, 18L, 23L, 19L, 15L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 17L, 7L, 1L, 
      3L, 6L, 4L, 20L, 21L, 18L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 
      5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 23L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
      6L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
      11L, 11L, 28L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 16L, 3L, 
      4L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = "data.frame")
tsibble2 <- dtd2 %>%
  mutate(Year = as_date(str_c(Year,"01",'01'))) %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = Year,key = Topic) %>%
  tsibble::fill_gaps(.full = TRUE) %>%
  group_by_key() %>% 
  index_by(year = Year %>% year) %>% 
  summarise(Count = Count %>% sum(na.rm = T)) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(year = year %>% as_factor())

tsibble2 %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = year,y = Count,color = Topic,group = Topic) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr` to add missing years and fill `Count` values with 0.

```
tidyr::complete(dtd2, Topic, Year = unique(Year), fill = list(Count = 0))

#A tibble: 108 x 3
#   Topic    Year  Count
#   <fct>    <fct> <dbl>
# 1 Topic 1  2011      3
# 2 Topic 1  2012      3
# 3 Topic 1  2013      3
# 4 Topic 1  2014      5
# 5 Topic 1  2015      5
# 6 Topic 1  2016     11
# 7 Topic 1  2017     17
# 8 Topic 1  2018     14
# 9 Topic 1  2019      4
#10 Topic 10 2011      0
# … with 98 more rows
```

and use it in `ggplot2` so that the lines are connected

```
library(ggplot2)
 tidyr::complete(dtd2, Topic, Year = unique(Year), fill = list(Count = 0)) %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Count, colour = Topic, group = Topic)) + 
   geom_point() + geom_line() + labs(x = "Year", y = NULL, title = "Timeline")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `expand`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dtd2 %>%
    expand(Topic = factor(Topic, levels = gtools::mixedsort(levels(Topic))) ,
                 Year = unique(Year)) %>% 
    left_join(dtd2) %>% 
    mutate(Count = replace_na(Count, 0)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Count, colour = Topic, group = Topic)) + 
         geom_point() +
         geom_line() +
         labs(x = "Year", y = NULL, title = "Timeline")
```

-output
[image]